# Sort an Array Given an array of integers nums, sort the array in ascending order. Input: nums = [5,2,3,1] Output: [1,2,3,5] Inp nums = [5,1,1,2,0,0]

Tags: c++, mergesort

## AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffdd2294ff8 (pc 0x000000345b86 bp 0x7ffdd22950d0 sp 0x7ffdd2295000 T0)
==32==ABORTING

```
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public: 
    
    void helper(std::vector<int>& nums, int start, int end) {

        if (start <= end) {

            int mid = (start + end) / 2;

            helper(nums, start, mid);
            helper(nums, mid + 1, end);

            int i = start;
            int j = mid;
            int k = mid + 1;
            int l = end;
            int m = 0;

            int ans[nums.size()];

            while (i < mid && k < end) {
                if (nums[i] < nums[j]) {
                    ans[m++] = nums[i++];
                }
                else {
                    ans[m++] = nums[j++];
                }
            }
            while (i < mid) {
                ans[m++] = nums[i++];
            }
            while (j < end) {
                ans[m++] = nums[j++];
            }
            i = start;
            j = end;

            while (i <= j) {
                nums[i++] = ans[i++];
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> sortArray(std::vector<int>& nums) {

        int n = nums.size() - 1;

        helper(nums, 0, n);

        std::vector<int>finalans;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {

            finalans.push_back(nums[i]);
        }
        return finalans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code.

1st, it does not compile. It contains invalid C++ code. VLAs (Variabale length arrays) are not a part of the C++ language. So, your line `int ans[nums.size()];` will not compile with a C++ compliant compiler.

2nd, and this is the root course of your crash, you do not have end end conditions for your recursion. In the 3rd line of your helper function, you call helper recursively and then again and again and again and again . . .

Until you get a stackoverflow or out of memory and the above error.

What you need to do is: Look in your algorithm book and try to understand mergesort. Then read it again and again and again. If you finally understood the algorithm (My guess is that it needs 10 days), then start coding. Not before. Otherwise you will definitely and always fail.

Try it.